# Font.createFont(..) set color and size (java.awt.Font)

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I'd like to create a new Font object using a TTF file. It is really simple to create a Font object but I don't know how to set color and size because I can't find a method for it?

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("helvetica.ttf");
Font helvetica = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Font's don't have a color; only when using the font you can set the color of the component. For example, when using a JTextArea:

```
JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
txt.setFont(font);
txt.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

According to [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html), the createFont() method creates a new Font object with a point size of 1 and style PLAIN. So, if you want to increase the size of the Font, you need to do this:

```
 Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("A.ttf"));
 return font.deriveFont(12f);
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, once you have your font, you can invoke `deriveFont`. For example,

```
helvetica = helvetica.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 12f);
```

Changes the font's style to bold and its size to 12 points.

Answer (score 0):

Because font doesn't have color, you need a panel to make a backgound color and give the foreground color for both JLabel (if you use JLabel) and JPanel to make font color, like example below :

```
JLabel lblusr = new JLabel("User name : ");
lblusr.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);

JPanel usrPanel = new JPanel();
Color maroon = new Color (128, 0, 0);
usrPanel.setBackground(maroon);
usrPanel.setOpaque(true);
usrPanel.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
usrPanel.add(lblusr);
```

The background color of label is maroon with yellow font color.

Answer (score -3):

To set the color of a font, you must first initialize the color by doing this:

```
Color maroon = new Color (128, 0, 0);
```

Once you've done that, you then put:

```
Font font = new Font ("Courier New", 1, 25); //Initializes the font
c.setColor (maroon); //Sets the color of the font
c.setFont (font); //Sets the font
c.drawString ("Your text here", locationX, locationY); //Outputs the string
```

Note: The 1 represents the type of font and this can be used to replace Font.PLAIN and the 25 represents the size of your font.